# Power BI how to shade campaigns periods on line chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

Looking to create a chart in Power BI that can shade periods on a line chart (x-axis = Date) & show Period Name labels like below with the following data. There are overlapping period so shading should be transparent & event labels should not overlap. Is this feasible in Power BI?

| Type | Period Name | Period Start Date | Period End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Giveaway | Giveaway 990 | 15-Sep-2023 | 25-Sep-2023 |
| Holiday | Holiday 1010 | 10-Oct-2023 | 17-Oct-2023 |
| Promotion | Promotion 20 | 9-Oct-2023 | 12-Oct-2023 |

[image]

Some similar tutorials but not quite:
[Learn how to HIGHLIGHT events on Power BI chart TIMELINE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1632Km1a2Y&list=RDCMUCKwBEguA8IlBubIobaOormg&start_radio=1&t=2s&ab_channel=ExcelFort)

[PUSH the limits of Power BI native VISUALS and CAPTIVATE your audience | TIMELINE chart Step-by-Step](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVy6rQMcmkg&ab_channel=HowtoPowerBI)